# How can an convergent series of rational numbers result in a irrational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

In mathematics, nearly all significant irrational numbers can be expressed as a sum of an infinite convergent series, but according to law of addition of rational numbers, adding any to rational numbers can not result in an irrational number.

So, why is this contradiction?

Comment: As long as finite many rational numbers are added, the result must , of course , be rational. But for infinite sums this is no longer true.

Comment: so, is it possible to represent iota(√-1) as a sum of infinite real numbers??

Comment: @Peter plz help me out, i forgot to include you

Comment: Even an infinite converging sum of real numbers has a real value. If your number is not real, it cannot be represented that way.

Comment: thnx @Peter for help

Comment: Also note that irrationality-proofs are , in general , extremely difficult. The sum $$\pi=4-4/3+4/5-4/7\pm \cdots $$ does not allow an easy proof that $\pi$ is irrational. In fact, $\pi+e$ is not known , but conjectured to be irrational.

Comment: @Peter but why, is this discrepancy, infinite rationals can add up to irrational, but infinite reals cannot add up to complex??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88534/discussion-between-peter-and-pranshukhandal).

Comment: why is my question rated negative?? is it a duplicate??

Comment: No idea, I cannot see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding any two rational numbers results in a rational number. By induction, adding any finite number of rational numbers together results in a rational number.

Adding together infinitely many rational numbers has no such guarantee, in exactly the same way that there is no guarantee that such a sum is finite.

Comment: so, is it possible to represent iota(√-1) as a sum of infinite real numbers??

Comment: thnx @Arthur for help

Comment: No, that isn't possible. An infinite sum of real numbers which converges is guaranteed to be real.